# How to prove the slope of the result of multiplying matrix A into a vector, is the same as the slope of eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra

Today we were advised by our mathematics teacher to take an arbitrary 2x2 matrix(for more convenience) and then multiply it many times(like ten) to a 2x1 vector. I checked that with A=
 \begin{array}{cc}
   2 & 1 \\
   2 & 3 \\
  \end{array} and B= \begin{array}{cc}
   1  \\
   2  \\
  \end{array}as the matrix and vector, respectively. We know that eigenvalues of A are 1 and 4. and eigen vectors or lines to be more specific, are $y=2x$ and $y=-x$.
I multiplied A into B for ten times by matlab, and yes, the second row element divided by the first row elements gives exactly 2, the slope of eigenvector line.

Now, I'm wondering about the proof, I tried to start by multiplying a parametric arbitrary matrix into a x,y vector, but couldn't reach to a result. Appreciate your hints or clues.

Comment: Try it with a diagonal matrix. That may help. What happens with the matrix whose rows are $0, -1$ and $1, 0$? I suggest you do that by hand, not with matlab.

Comment: It should come as no surprise that the slope matches that of an eigenvector of $A$ since you started out with one, so all that happened is that its length changed. What happens if $B$ _isn’t_ and eigenvector of $A$?

Comment: @amd yeah you are right, but I changed the B, and now the slope is 2 again.

Comment: @EthanBolker in the case of the matrix you said, the eigenvalues are complex.

Comment: I doubt that it’s _exactly_ $2$. E.g., using $B=(1,1)^T$, the resulting slope is exactly $1398101/699051$, which is close but not equal to $2$.

Comment: @MohammadHoseinKhalili  I know. But your teacher seems not to have said the eigenvalues must be real (s/he should have). When they are real, express a vector as a linear combination of eigenvectors and see what happens - by hand. What if the eigenvalues are $100$ and $1$?

Comment: @amd yeah he actually said A^n which n goes to infinity, but for n=10 it is near 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are a phd student in Bio Engg. I am guessing you are starting a linear algebra course in the fall semester so welcome to the the land of matrices :)

Before I give more details about what you observed, let's start by clearing one thing. What your teacher said is a partial truth.

Let $M = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix},$ and let $v_1 = [1, 1]^T.$ and $v_2 = [-1, 1]^T$. The only candidates for eigenvalues of $M$ are $-1$ and $1$. Clearly $Mv = v$ so $1$ and $v$ are eigenvalue and eigenvector and similarly $-1, v_2$ are eigenvalue, eigenvector pair.  Now take an arbitrary vector $b = [x, y]^T$. When you multiply it many times with $M$ you will see that you can only get either $[x, y]$ or $[y, x]$ and this will happen regardless of what $y$ and $x$ were. So this is a counterexample to the phenomenon you observed.

Now, the computation that you did in your question was an example of the [Power iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) algorithm. The wikipedia page states three requirements without which the algorithm need not work.

1. The matrix should be diagonalizable
2. The matrix has an eigenvalue that is strictly greater in magnitude than its other eigenvalues.
3. The starting vector $b$ has a nonzero component in the direction of an eigenvector associated with the dominant eigenvalue.

In my example condition 2. was not satisfied so power iteration failed. You can try to violate 3. or 1. and 3. simultaneously and you will also see that power iteration will fail.